# Shortcut Key to start the android application

Tags: android

I need a shortcut key that when pressed, my app itself launches. Can somebody please help me what code I should use to create such shortcut?
My app code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();     
        values.put("address", "5554");               
        values.put("body", "hayee_wardah!");               
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), values);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  Can you try and clarify your exact issue?  Post screen shots if English is difficult, and try and indicate what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: A short cut key?  What do you mean?  Do you mean when the user presses a certain key combination?

Comment: i mean when the user presses a certain key my app will launch automatically

Comment: You can't as the answer below states.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to capture the keys in the Android. For ex. If you are looking to once user has pressed 123 then start the application.

But You can do such dial a specific unique number and in the broadcast call receiver you can start your application.

You have to register the Outgoing Call Receiver for this.

Check in the receiver that outgoing call is on the same number (Unique Number). If it so then disconnect the call and start the application.